# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation.constructAppearances()'

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

iam creating extent PDF and html report in selenium cucumber java. report is creating in html format without any fail. PdfReport folder is creating under test output folder. but Report is not generating. I created extent.properties ,extent-config.xml files and add depencies to pm.xml.  It shows the following error:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: void org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.annotation.PDAnnotation.constructAppearances()

`````
    at org.vandeseer.easytable.drawing.cell.ParagraphCellDrawer.drawContent(ParagraphCellDrawer.java:57)
    at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.lambda$new$0(TableDrawer.java:61)
    at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.drawRow(TableDrawer.java:170)
    at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.drawWithFunction(TableDrawer.java:153)
    at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.lambda$drawPage$1(TableDrawer.java:83)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.drawPage(TableDrawer.java:82)
    at org.vandeseer.easytable.TableDrawer.draw(TableDrawer.java:78)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.chapter.detailed.DetailedRowComponent.display(DetailedRowComponent.java:90)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.chapter.detailed.DetailedPage.lambda$0(DetailedPage.java:42)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.chapter.detailed.DetailedPage.createPage(DetailedPage.java:39)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.chapter.detailed.DetailedChapter.sendToPage(DetailedChapter.java:115)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.chapter.detailed.DetailedChapter.createAndSendPageData(DetailedChapter.java:104)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.chapter.detailed.DetailedChapter.createChapter(DetailedChapter.java:28)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.PDFCucumberReport.lambda$0(PDFCucumberReport.java:100)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.PDFCucumberReport.createReport(PDFCucumberReport.java:100)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.extent.ExtentPDFCucumberReporter.flush(ExtentPDFCucumberReporter.java:66)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.extent.ExtentPDFCucumberReporter.access$1(ExtentPDFCucumberReporter.java:57)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.extent.ExtentPDFCucumberReporter$1.onNext(ExtentPDFCucumberReporter.java:42)
    at tech.grasshopper.pdf.extent.ExtentPDFCucumberReporter$1.onNext(ExtentPDFCucumberReporter.java:1)
    at io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishDisposable.onNext(PublishSubject.java:310)
    at io.reactivex.rxjava3.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:226)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ReactiveSubject.onFlush(ReactiveSubject.java:83)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.AbstractProcessor.onFlush(AbstractProcessor.java:85)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports.flush(ExtentReports.java:284)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter.finishReport(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:296)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter.access$6(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:295)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter$8.receive(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:132)
    at com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter$8.receive(ExtentCucumberAdapter.java:1)
    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventPublisher.send(AbstractEventPublisher.java:51)
    at io.cucumber.core.eventbus.AbstractEventBus.send(AbstractEventBus.java:12)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.emitTestRunFinished(CucumberExecutionContext.java:93)
    at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.finishTestRun(CucumberExecutionContext.java:74)
    at io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber$RunCucumber.evaluate(Cucumber.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)```


pom.xml

    ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.automatedtest.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>automated-test-sample</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>jitpack.io</id>
            <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-alpha-4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.0</version>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.9.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.ralfstuckert.pdfbox-layout</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox2-layout</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
   <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
   <version>2.8.4</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


   </dependencies>

    <build>
    
      
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                 <source>1.8</source>
                 <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <exclude>**/*Runner.java</exclude>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>````


extent.properties
-------------------

    ```extent.reporter.pdf.start=true
extent.reporter.json.start=true;
extent.reporter.spark.start=true

extent.reporter.json.out=test output/PdfReport/jsonoutput.json
extent.reporter.pdf.out=test output/PdfReport/pdfoutput.pdf
extent.reporter.spark.out=test-output/SparkReport/Spark.html
extent.reporter.spark.config=src/test/resources/extent-config.xml

extent.reporter.spark.out=test-output/SparkReport/

screenshot.dir=test-output/
screenshot.rel.path=../


#basefolder.name=reports
#basefolder.datetimepattern=d-MMM-YY HH-mm-ss
extent.reporter.spark.vieworder=dashboard,test,category,exception,author,device,log
systeminfo.os=Windows
systeminfo.user=Bismi
systeminfo.AppName=IWITS HQ```

extent-config.xml
--------------------

    ```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extentreports>
    <configuration>
        <!-- report theme -->

        <!-- standard, dark -->

        <theme>dark</theme>
        <!-- document encoding -->

        <!-- defaults to UTF-8 -->

        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        <!-- protocol for script and stylesheets -->

        <!-- defaults to https -->

        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <!-- title of the document -->
        <documentTitle>Extent</documentTitle>
        <!-- report name - displayed at top-nav -->

        <reportName>Grasshopper Report</reportName>
        <!-- location of charts in the test view -->

        <!-- top, bottom -->

        <testViewChartLocation>bottom</testViewChartLocation>
        <!-- custom javascript -->

        <!-- offlineMode>true</offlineMode -->

        <scripts>

<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {
});
]]>
        </scripts>
        <!-- custom styles -->
        <styles>
<![CDATA[
]]>
        </styles>
    </configuration>
</extentreports>```




Runner.java
-------------

    ```package com.automatedtest.sample.TestRunner;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = {"src/test/resources/Feature/IR2131.feature"},
        glue = {"com.automatedtest.sample.driver",
                "com.automatedtest.sample.stepdefinition"},
         plugin = {"pretty",
                 "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}        
)
public class Runner {
    
}```
`````

Answer (score 0):

Please try again after adding the below two dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.24</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.vandeseer/easytable -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.vandeseer</groupId>
    <artifactId>easytable</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had the same issue.
After adding the below dependencies it worked and now the cucumber extent reports both html and pdf are generating as expected with no failures.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.24</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.vandeseer/easytable -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.vandeseer</groupId>
    <artifactId>easytable</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please read the original issue reported and I tried the resolution provided which worked for me.